# PHP strtotime thinks 24h input is 12h?

Tags: php, datetime, timezone, timestamp, strtotime

`strtotime('31.07.2017 08:17')` outputs as `1501478160` which is exactly **12h** ahead of what it should be **(31.07.2017 08:17pm UTC+02:00)** but since it is military time that I give it, then it should be **08:17** in the morning instead!

I have all the `time zones` set correctly.
What am I missing here? How do I tell the `strtotime` that I want to give it time as 24h format?

Thanks

Comment: Do you call it somewhere in a formatted string?

Comment: Add you code here how you are getting the time?

Comment: Okay basically I use datetimepicker that outputs it's time and date into input box and javascript + PHP retreive it from there and convert it as string into timestamp. Which part code do you want? My code in total is very long it would be quite counterproductive to post it as whole here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strtotime` involves some guesswork to figure out what your input means. I tested it myself and got `08:17` (AM), so it's possible that locale settings are having something to do with it.

In any event, if you know the format then you should prefer `DateTime::createFromFormat()` and tell it exactly what to expect:

```
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('!d.m.Y H:i','31.07.2017 08:17');
```

You can now do various things with the object, and eventually:

```
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s'); // or whatever format you want
```

Comment: this is quite interesting, how would I echo $dt->format() as timestamp?

Comment: Never mind I figured it out it's ('U') HOWEVER it still outputs the wrong timestamp, I think the error is somewhere else then

Comment: The next thing I would check is [`date_default_timezone_get`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php). If it's something unexpected, try correcting it with `date_default_timezone_set` and/or passing the timezone explicitly to `createFromFormat`.

Comment: Wait! I think it was a human error after all. I used a website to convert unix to datetime and then converted the given datetime to my local timezone separately in another website. Something there went wrong because when I convert the timestamp to datetime in PHP it gives the correct thing haha. Looks like my mistake I'm terribly sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace

```
strtotime('31.07.2017 08:17');
```

with

```
strtotime('31.07.2017 08:17PM');
```

And check it again .
Just mention the **AM** or **PM** in your **String**